# Conversion to full-width characters, Unicode error on Window with Python 3

Tags: python, windows, unicode

I'm trying to convert an alphanumeric string to Japanese full-width characters in Python 3.8.3 on Windows.

The below code works on an OSX machine:

```
import sys

def convert_to_full_width(s):
    """Converts string to full-width characters.

    Args:
        s (str): Alphanumeric text.

    Returns:
        (str): Text in full-width characters.
    """
    WIDE_MAP = dict((i, i + 0xFEE0) for i in range(0x21, 0x7F))
    WIDE_MAP[0x20] = 0x3000

    return s.translate(WIDE_MAP)

print(convert_to_full_width("XYZ123"))
```

But throws the following error in VSCode on Windows:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Your command-line interpreter/IDE console uses an 8-bit codepage instead of a codec with full Unicode support (such as UTF-8). It's an environment issue, not something you can fix from within Python. (Within Python, you can only circumvent the problem by not using `print()`.)

Comment: It works fine with a regular console window and the IDLE shell. It must be limited to VSCode.

Comment: run `chcp 65001` to change to UTF-8

Comment: @phuclv, the console's byte-string API does not support reading keyboard or pasted console input as UTF-8 for non-ASCII characters (i.e. character ordinals above 127). Since `chcp.com 65001` sets both the input and output codepages to UTF-8, it's broken except for English-speaking locales that only care about non-ASCII *output* (i.e. it's anglocentric advice). It's also completely unnecessary for Python 3.6+, which uses the console's wide-character (UTF-16) API under the hood and exposes it to Python code as UTF-8.